# Powershell find a file in root dir with excludes

Tags: powershell

I have the following code to try locating a folder within my project.

```
$rootDir = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path

    $fileName = "Scripts*"
    $paths = gci -path $rootDir -filter $fileName -Recurse | Select-Object -Expand FullName
```

The problem I am having is that I don't want it finding the folder inside of bin or obj folder. Is there a way to exclude those from the search?

Basically I need to recursively search my solution folder for a folder name, excluding the bin/obj locations.

When I try using the -Exclude it gives my compile errors. I imagine there has to be a easier way than this to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that -Exclude only accepts strings. You'll need to use Where-Object to filter out multiple strings.

```
$paths = gci -path $rootDir -filter $fileName -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.FullName -notlike "*bin*\*" -and $_.FullName -notlike "*obj*\*"} | Select-Object -Expand FullName
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the -Exclude is passed along to the Provider, and the file system provider is not good at filtering in general. I would suggest using a Where clause and using one of the -Match operators (-inotmatch is a case insensitive inverted match, so it excludes anything that matches the text) like this:

```
$rootDir = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$fileName = "Scripts*"
$paths = gci -path $rootDir -filter $filename -Recurse | Select-Object -Expand FullName | ?{$_ -inotmatch "\\(bin|obj)\\"}
```

That looks for a string that starts with a backslash (), followed by either bin or obj, and trailed by another backslash.